# Image is not updating in app using picasso

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, picasso

When I am trying to update image in my app it's not updating but in firebase storage updating
I am used

> Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImage);

I am also tried with

> Picasso.with(SetupActivity.class).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImage);

These are my dependencies

> ```
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
>
>     implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
>
>     implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
>
>     implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
>
>     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
>     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
> ```

Comment: can you show us your database structure on where you get this url value dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString(); it might be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picasso does cache images but if your image has a different URI it downloads it but the former image is still cached, you can 'invalidate' to remove the former image, then load the recent one.

`Picasso.with(bContext).invalidate(bFileURI); //invalidates files`

If your structure is such that you overwrite images using same URI and you don't want it to cache at all then go for

`Picasso.with(bContext)
    .load(bImage_url)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_img)
    .into(bImageView);`

(I would rather invalidate as the latter is not a good practice for offline use)

Since you are using Firebase, you can also consider this and save the byte as string in SharePreference for offline use... Bad practice still.

```
final long bOneMB = 1024 * 1024;                               //size 
userProfileImageRef.getBytes(bOneMB)                           //get byte
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {       // add listener
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {                     // called if successful
            Bitmap bBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(bBitmap);                // sets bitmap in image view
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am tried like this Picasso.get()
                                .load(image)
                                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
                                .into(profileImage);                but not working

Comment: bro any alternative is there, without using picasso ??

Comment: You can use glide

Comment: I tried glide like this Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImage);   still not working

Comment: You can also try invalidating... Glide is pretty fast, save images in ranges, but it still caches.

Comment: Glide.with(SetupActivity.this)
                                .load(image)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                                .into(profileImage);     Still not working

Comment: Are you sure the image was uploaded? can I get to see your recent code?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q9g3ZV5y4H9bVs2RlS0m5qUV5sUfkQpu/view?usp=sharing      visit this link I uploaded my code drive

Comment: I would have loved the help of some comments on your code... it aids readability... not to worry. I am reading it

Comment: So I added another method and hope it will help. I have used 'invalidate' on picasso and glide and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)` and  `.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)` in picasso.